# Grayscale depth image to point cloud data

Tags: grayscale, depth, point-cloud-library

I am trying to convert grayscale depth image(0-255) to cloud points xyz to work on them in PCL(point cloud library).

Any ideas of how I could do so?

Comment: Well, what is your data source? What does the grey scale value mean?

Comment: I could not figure if the greyscale was actual greyscale or represented depth? Also, as Bart notes, the data source determines the camera model, whether it needs to use calibration information, etc.

Comment: I use two stereo images to create a depth map which is just an image of grey-scale values. White meaning close to the camera, black being away from the camera.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to know the camera Intrinsic parameters(K), if the world coordinate reference system is different from the camera's, you also need to know the Extrinsic parameters(R & T) of the camera. Then you can get the projection matrix P. According to the projection relation between 2d image and cloud points you can compute the position of the points with the correspond depth.